# How to add scroll into listItem of list on search

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I have a List which contains ListItem and a search bar. Search functionality is working well as per the requirement and its highlighting the ListItem. Now i am trying to add the scroll so that the List gets scroll to first occurrence of the 'includes' if the search item is not available on visible window but not able to implement it. Tried  `const ref = React.createRef();`

How to get it working?

Here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cvt4f?file=/demo.js)

Comment: so as soon as you enter that page you want it to scroll to the bottom ?

Comment: @CyrusZei As search text is entered in search bar, if the text does not match within the visible window, then it should scroll down to first occurrence in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this one using vanilla js.

First just store the `index` of all matching ListItem in a state:

```js
  const getMatchingListItems = React.useCallback(() => {
    return [...messages]
      .map(({ id, primary, secondary, person }, i) => {
        if (secondary.includes(searchTranscript) && searchTranscript !== "") {
          return i;
        }
      })
      .filter((elmt) => elmt !== undefined);
  }, [searchTranscript]);

  const [matchingListItems, setMatchingListItems] = useState(getMatchingListItems());
```

Use it to define which `className` to use:

```html
<div
  className={
    matchingListItems.includes(i) ? classes.searchHighLight : ""
  }
```

And finally use the `useEffect` hook to scroll to the first matching LisItem when `matchingListItems` is updated:

```js
   React.useEffect(() => {
    setMatchingListItems(getMatchingListItems());
  }, [getMatchingListItems, setMatchingListItems]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const firstListMatch = matchingListItems[0];

    if (firstListMatch) {
      const firstLi = document.querySelector(
        `ul div:nth-child(${firstListMatch})`
      );
      firstLi.scrollIntoView();
    } else {
      document.querySelector("ul").scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, [matchingListItems]);
```

You can try it using this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nn9pn?file=/demo.js).

Comment: thanks so much..just one thing wanted to ask, how to add the scroll transition, currently its jumping, how to add smooth scroll transition?

Comment: Well `scrollIntoView()` can get an object as parameter (check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)). One of the options is `behavior` wich can take `auto` or `smooth` as value. So if you want a smooth scroll transition call `firstLi.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })`

Comment: thanks but don't know for some reason, its not getting applied and its making the scroll functionality go as well? Could you please update this in sandbox?

Comment: @Lara I test it and you're right it doesn't work :/ Not exactly sure why since the `scrollIntoView` is called but nothing append. Would be better to open a new question for this behavior with a minimal reproductible example (I would love to make some research for it). So if it's ok for you could you please `validate` this answer?